# How to use np.random.uniform() for real world examples

Tags: python, probability

[image: I want to solve this image question by using numpy]

**What I tried**

```
from numpy import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import seaborn as sns

sns.distplot(random.uniform(0,30, 5), hist=True)

plt.show()
```

*Result which I got*
Here its showing 8% and 12%, but my required answer as according to manual prediction is 16%. I think I am confused about the *size* parameter in `random.binomial()
[image: output]

Comment: you have density of probability on negative values, I dont understand what you are doing but someone can not wait for -5 minutes so whatever you are doing is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to simulate the result.

Try the following

```
import numpy as np

# sample 100k uniform random values (it can be any large number) from 0 to 30
waiting_time = np.random.uniform(0, 30, size = 100_000) 

# caclulate the proportion that are between 10 and 15
np.mean((waiting_time >=10) & (waiting_time <= 15)) 
# will be around 0.166 i.e. around 16.6%.
```

Plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.distplot(waiting_time)
plt.show();

# OR
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(waiting_time);
```

[image]